# Schema objects not visible in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm experiencing a weird problem with a SQL login. When I connect to the server in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (2008) using this account, I cannot see any of the tables, stored procedures etc. that this account should have access to on a particular database.

When I connect to the same server within Visual Studio (2008) with the same account everything is there. When I connect with the same account on a Virtual Machine everything is there. I've also had a co-worker connect to the server using the same login and he's able to view everything as well.

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio all day connecting to different servers and databases and I've never experienced this problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can diagnose this problem?

I've checked to make sure I don't have any Table filters etc.

There's several database on this server and I'm able to see the correct tables that this account has access to in the other databases just fine.

Running this query lists the tables I'm expecting to see.

```
 SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: I would be double and triple checking that you are connecting to the same database on the same server with both products.

Comment: quadruple checked, same server, same sql login, different results. I'm just setting up a VM for additional test.

Comment: Could it be you’re connecting to another Instance within the same server? Perform a simple test. Insert a row in one place, see if you can query it on the “other”.

Comment: I'm able to query the tables that I cannot see.

Comment: Where are they "invisible"? In the Object Explorer tree view? Do you happen to have a filter active by any chance??

Comment: @marc_s I'm not able to see tables/stored procedures etc. in Object Explorer on one database, the others are fine. I did check to make sure I didn't have any filters applied. I connected with a VM and I can view everything just fine. Not being able to view the tables isn't preventing me from querying them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved my problem. It's a bug... Here are the details.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/387616/tables-node-does-not-show-all-schemas-in-ssmse-2008

Answer (score 0):

fire up SQL Profiler then refresh the database list in SQLSMS and see what the query is that it uses to list the databases.

Answer (score 0):

you can restart sql management to fix it.